# What is the difference between BEFORE, SENTBEFORE, and SAVEDBEFORE?

Tags: dovecot

In [`doveadm-search-query(7)`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/man7/doveadm-search-query.7.html), it states:

> **BEFORE** date specification
>     Matches messages with an internal date before date specification.

> **SENTBEFORE** date specification
>     Matches messages with a Date: header before date specification.

> **SAVEDBEFORE** date specification
>     Matches messages, which were saved before date specification.

I am creating a `cron` job to purge old messages in Trash or Spam folders, but I discovered using `doveadm search` queries using `savedbefore` that somehow no message in any of the folders shows up with queries starting at `5d`, even though there are years old messages.

```
doveadm search mailbox Trash before 90d -A | wc -l
277
doveadm search mailbox Trash sentbefore 90d -A | wc -l
277
doveadm search mailbox Trash savedbefore 90d -A | wc -l
0
```

For my purpose, I'm not clear on the differences between the different queries and am wondering what will be the better option.